# Gradle 6.2 copy doesn't fail if file is missing

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am copying files using a `copy` block in Gradle 6.2 as follows but it does not fail if the file is missing.

```
copy {
    from file("$project.projectDir/ABC.toml")
    into file("${artifactDir}/XYZ")
}
```

How can I make the copying fail if `"$project.projectDir/ABC.toml"` file is missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it fail by checking the existence of the file manually and if it's absent, then throw an exception.

```
task copyMethod {
    doFirst {
        if (!file("ABC.toml").exists()) {
            throw new GradleException("ABC.toml not found")
        }
    }

    doLast {
        copy {
            from "ABC.toml"
            into "${artifactDir}/XYZ"
        }
    }
}
```